# Is the performance of ref.endAt().limit(n).on(...) similar for .priority and name?

Tags: firebase

I am currently using `ref.endAt().limit(n).on(...)` to get the 'last' n values.

All the `.priority` are null so the list is sorted by name which is a 0 padded timestamp

It seemed that if I set the `.priority` of each item also to the timestamp that it would take more storage.  Does it?

Regardless of whether or not it takes more storage, is there a significant performance difference for retrieving the last n sorted items if `.priority` is all null (so name sort is used) or if `.priority` are all unique and that .priority sort is used?

I am currently designing for it to work well with 10,000 ish items in a list.  Is `.priority` or name sort better when a list gets over 1,000,000 items?

What about using `ref.startAt(null, timeStart).endAt(null, timeEnd).on(...)`?

I could profile, but how would I know that server load or network delays are or are not affecting it?

Comment: I am not seeing any performance advantage using startAt() and endAt() to get a subset of a large node.

Example: It takes ~2 seconds to get a 10,000 element object.  If I break this up into smaller chunks by using startAt().limit(1000), each of the 10 calls also take ~2 seconds.  In fact each call seems to take even longer than the single callback with no startAt() or limit().

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance difference between using priority or key names to sort items. Firebase first looks for priority to sort items, and if it doesn't exist, sorts items by key name. There might be a very small performance gain by using priority instead of key name, but I expect this to very small.